# Implementation of insertion sort in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I have written an insertion sort algorithm in JavaScript:

```
function insertionSort(inputArray){ 
  var totalElements = inputArray.length - 1;
  var temp = 0;
  var lastIndex = 0;
  var prevIndex = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i <= totalElements; i++){
    for(var currentIndex = i; currentIndex > lastIndex; currentIndex--){
        prevIndex = currentIndex - 1;                           
        if(inputArray[currentIndex] < inputArray[prevIndex]){
            temp = inputArray[currentIndex];
            inputArray[currentIndex] = inputArray[prevIndex];
            inputArray[prevIndex] = temp;                                
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }

  }

  return inputArray;
}

console.log(insertionSort([1,31,26,4,3,12]));
console.log(insertionSort([5,6,1,2,3,4]));
```

The output is also proper:

> ```
> rahul@rahul:~/myPractise/Algo$ node sorting.js 
> [ 1, 3, 4, 12, 26, 31 ]
> [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
> rahul@rahul:~/myPractise/Algo$
> ```

Can this be further improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your function can only sort numbers and strings**

The built in `Array.sort` function offers an optional compare function as a parameter. Adding this feature to your `insertionSort` function would allow for users to sort any type of object:

```
function defaultCompare(x, y) {
  if (x < y)
    return -1;
  else if (x > y)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

function insertionSort(array, compare) {
  compare = compare ? compare : defaultCompare;
  //...
}
```

**You have quite a few variables that aren't necessary**

**`totalElements`**

You only use this variable once, in the condition of your first `for` loop. JavaScript has some incredibly fast engines and with JIT-Compiler (just in time compiler) you don't have to worry about micromanaging optimizations like what if js isn't smart enough to know that it's recalculating `inputArray.length - 1` each iteration. Defining `totalElements` arguably makes your code harder to read by adding another variable the scope, and the JS engines are smart-enough/fast-enough that performance isn't likely affected, so I would recommend getting rid of it.

**`temp`**

You could eliminate `temp` by abstracting out a function to swap indices in an array:

```
function swapIndices(array, index1, index2) {
  var temp = array[index1];
  array[index1] = array[index2];
  array[index2] = temp;
}
```

This also improves your code's cohesiveness by abstracting out the technicalities of swapping variables, and it allows you to use `swapIndices` elsewhere in your code.

**`lastIndex`**

This one is just a constant for zero. At the very least you should change the `var` to `const`:

```
const lastIndex = 0;
```

But I'd recommend to just get rid of it.

**`prevIndex`**

I find `currentIndex - 1` more clear than `prevIndex`. The former is obviously the index 1 less than `currentIndex` whereas the latter could also mean the previously swapped element (precedingIndex is another possible name).

**Summary**

With all the above changes your code would look like:

```
function defaultCompare(x, y) {
  if (x < y)
    return -1;
  else if (x > y)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

function swapIndices(array, index1, index2) {
  var temp = array[index1];
  array[index1] = array[index2];
  array[index2] = temp;
}

function insertionSort(array, compare) {
  compare = compare ? compare : defaultCompare;

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (let currIndex = i; currIndex > 0; currIndex--) {
      if (compare(array[currIndex], array[currIndex - 1]) < 0) {
        swapIndices(array, currIndex, currIndex - 1);
      }
      else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading and running your code, I thought I could make your life easier by  turning this pseudocode at [Insertion Sort](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/insertion_sort_algorithm.htm) to javascript.

```js
   function insertionSort(inputArray){
    var holePosition
    var valueToInsert
    
    for(var i = 1; i< inputArray.length; i++){
     
          /* select value to be inserted */
          valueToInsert = inputArray[i]
          holePosition = i
          
    /* Notice I used the while as opposed to the for*/
    while ( holePosition > 0 && inputArray[holePosition-1] > valueToInsert){
             inputArray[holePosition] = inputArray[holePosition-1]
             holePosition = holePosition -1
          
      }
          /* insert the number at hole position */
          inputArray[holePosition] = valueToInsert
    }
    return inputArray;
    }
var result =insertionSort([1,31,26,4,3,12]);
alert('['+ result.join() + ']');
```

**Note:**

- So many variables were defined `totalElements`, `temp`, `lastIndex` and `prevIndex` which were unnecessary. In the code below, I utilised two variables called `holePosition` and `valueToInsert` to serve as Positions for insertion and the values to include in those positions
- I have also replaced your second for statement with a while loop. I would use **while loop** with a continuous sorting as opposed to a for loop